# i want to add link in every column but because of bootstrap properties whenever I try ,it just disturb the styling

Tags: html, css, grid, bootstrap-5, styling

so How can without disturbing the styling I could add link in each columns , sorry for the crapy code I'm just newbie in this field

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
            <a href="#"><div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 my-sm-2 cbi_1" id="cbi">
                <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                    Digital Creator
                </div>
            </div></a>
            <div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 px-1 my-sm-2 cbi_2" id="cbi">
                <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                    graphic designer
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 px-1 my-sm-2 cbi_3" id="cbi">
                <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                    Web Designer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: insert before and after of adding `link` to code for better reproduce problem

Answer (score 1):

Only wrap the content with link instead of full row:

```
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 my-sm-2 cbi_1" id="cbi">
            <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                <a href>Digital Creator</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 px-1 my-sm-2 cbi_2" id="cbi">
            <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                <a href>graphic designer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 py-5 ms-3 px-1 my-sm-2 cbi_3" id="cbi">
            <div class="col-txt-box text-center  text-dark text-uppercase">
                <a href>Web Designer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a bunch your idea is great ,its really work...look like I have focus on more possibility